# Text after table in Word using VBA codes

Tags: excel, vba

I create a Word document using VBA codes and transfer data from Excel to a table I create in the Word document.

I get an error starting a new line/paragraph after the table.

My code selects the whole table but does not start new text after the table, so later content is being added to cell(1,1) in the table.

I am just showing you the structure of my codes and I get an error at the `Selection.Collapse` line of code.

> run time error 438, object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Sub Word_Report()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
    With objWord.Selection
        Set myTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objWord.Selection.Range, NumRows:=7, NumColumns:=3)
        myTable.Borders.Enable = True

        ''' my table contents'''
    end with

    'start new line after table
    objDoc.Range.InsertAfter Chr(13) & "Hello"
    .Font.Size = 11
    .BoldRun

End sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edited

Try the following:

```
   Sub Word_Report()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()




     With objWord.Selection
    Set myTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objWord.Selection.Range, NumRows:=7, NumColumns:=3)
      myTable.Borders.Enable = True

    ''' my table contents'''
    End With

    'start new line after table
    objDoc.Range.InsertAfter Chr(13) & "Hello"

    End Sub
```

Use `.Range` instead of `Selection`

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I am getting the same error at the second line of codes you posted.

Comment: I have modified my codes based on yours so let me know if I did something wrong.

Comment: I am trying to add blank row and start a new line but when I add .typetext after insertafter " ", it's still populating in the table cell(1,1) anyway to fix that? i can't seem to use typeparagraph or typetext.

Comment: I posted my desire results and modified my currents and I can't seem to modify your codes to suit my needs. I put (blank row) so you know there is a space and I m hoping to use .typeparagraph or typetext since that how I am inputting my texts afterwards.

Comment: The image help me to understand what you was trying to do. Edited again. Try the code, it should work now.

Comment: Thank you for your input, now I get blank row but "Hello" is still in cell(1,1) of the table. I think the issue is the cursor is in the table or the way I use with range.

Comment: Hi, I did but I can't seem to incorporate yours with .typeparagraph, .boldrun or .typetext can you try?

Comment: Everything after insert after that line of code will be bounced back to cell(1,1) of the table for some reason and I am thinking it's because the cursor is pointing that and I tried to add page break after the table and it's just moves the whole table to next page.

Comment: I will start a new question since you answer partial of my answers. Thanks

Comment: Thanks David, I found something that works online. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To insert text immediately following at table, you have to **set the range** to the table then **collapse the range**.  Insert your table, flow all your data into it, format the table.

When you've got it how you want it, use code like this where `h1` is a `Word.Range` and `objTemplate` is a `Word.Document` object:

```
Set h1 = objTemplate.Tables(TableNum).Range

h1.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
```